# What is the right way to perform corrections in the prayer?

Tags: salat, fiqh, practical-islam

I know about sujud sahw etc.

But what is unclear to me is the correct proceeding while praying if one discovered a mistake, let me give some excamples:

- You stood up for the third rak'a started recitation and recalled, you doidn't perform the tahiyyat at the end of the 2nd rak'a: Should one go back in the sitting position and re-do the tahiyyat and stand up etc. and perfrom sujud sahw at the end or should one go on praying and do sujud sahw at the end of the prayer.
- While reciting the surah ro verses after al-Fatihah you remember that you should recite loudly (in fajr/maghrib/'isha' first two raka'a) or sielentlently (in dhor/'asr) can I simply restart from al-Fatihah or correct from the point I've discovered my mistake
- One stood up and recalled that one already prayed the full amount of raka'as again should the raka'a be completed or should one go down in a sitting position?

So this is mainly about mistakes that one have discovered a moment too late to proceed in a correct manner.

I'd appreciate an answer covering all scholarly views (and conditions).
However any answer covering one view would be fine as long as you add this information.